# connecting docker container with mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

How to connect with mysql in my local machine with mysql running inside the docker container.
Also i need to know how to import a .dmp file in my local machine to my mysql running inside a docker container.

Comment: maybe you want share your local volume between host and container, if so use `-v` when start container

Comment: docker run -d -v ~/test:/var/log/mysql -p 5000:3306 -i mysql-server  i used this command to run the conatiner..but its not connecting with the local mysql

Comment: `-v` is using for share locale file, if you want to copy dmp file to cantainer use cp command after you start container

Answer (score 0):

What do I understand that you have MySQL docker container and you need to access that (query database)?

To access MySQL docker container, you can use

> docker exec -it mysql_container-name mysql -uroot -p
>
> “root” is the username for MySQL database.
> After running above command it will ask you a password.

After successful login, it will show you MySQL console, where you can run various queries on your database.
example:

To Select Database

> USE Database_name;

Show tables

> show tables;

Take a back-up or restore MySQL Database from Docker containers.

> **Backup MySQL database**:
>
> docker exec mysql_container_name /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=1234 Database_name > backup.sql
>
> **Restore MySQL database**:
>
> cat backup.sql | docker exec -i mysql_container_name /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=1234 Database_name

Hope this helps.

For more Docker commands please follow below link
https://rohanjmohite.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/docker-daily-useful-commands/

Comment: Thank you Rohan ... is it possible to upload a .dmp file which reside in my machine to the sql running in the container..?

Comment: do you mean import database file into MySQL Container?

Comment: Yes... is it possible? and how?

Comment: Yes, it is, I have added both commands to take a backup and restore the backup from MySQL docker container. Please have a look and let me know in case any further help required?